# jquery.FilterTable preset value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So I'm using sunnywalker's jquery.filterTable plugin to filter through tables.
Now i'm trying to link to that page from another url with a preset filter, I thought that I could simply generate the following code using PHP

```
$('#input-filter').val(<?= $_GET['q'] ?>).trigger('key_up');
```

This tho does not work.
Is there any way to make this work without having to rewrite the full page just to apply a filter here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

I used key_up instead of keyup.